# Fit chi squared distribution with Pymc

Tags: python, pymc

I am trying to fit a Chi-squared distribution using Pymc:

```
# Context for the model
with pm.Model() as normal_model:
    # The prior for the model parameters will be a normal distribution
    family = pm.ChiSquared("nc_chi2", nu=2)
    # Creating the model requires a formula and data (and optionally a family)
    pm.GLM.from_formula(formula, data=X_train, family=family)

    # Perform Markov Chain Monte Carlo sampling
    normal_trace = pm.sample(draws=2000, chains=2, tune=500)
```

Is this a correct approach for positive real data between 3 and 40? I am getting the error `AttributeError: 'TransformedRV' object has no attribute 'create_likelihood'`